# TypeError: _app2.default.database is not a function. (In '_app2.default.database()', '_app2.default.database' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this error is strange .What wrong in react native in firebase
I installed firebase already by npm install
here is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'
import Card from './card'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import database from 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA_AXaJ_hLC3jXMOIjaXLyktgX1t7e--FU",
  authDomain: "tinderclone-99d8e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tinderclone-99d8e",
  storageBucket: "tinderclone-99d8e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "264605926507",
  appId: "1:264605926507:web:c9309a6669322ef6839d2e",
  databaseURL:'https://tinderclone-99d8e-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/'
  
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    profileIndex: 0,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').once('value', (snap) => {
      console.log('Data', snap.val())
    })
  }


  nextCard = () => {
    this.setState({profileIndex: this.state.profileIndex + 1})
  }

  render() {
    const {profileIndex} = this.state
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {profiles.slice(profileIndex, profileIndex + 3).reverse().map((profile) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={profile.id}
              profile={profile}
              onSwipeOff={this.nextCard}
            />
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const profiles = [
  {
    id: '259389830744794',
    name: 'Candice',
    birthday: '10/18/1986',
    bio: 'Supermodel',
  },
  {
    id: '720115413',
    name: 'Alessandra',
    birthday: '1/10/1989',
    bio: 'Dancer',
  },
  {
    id: '169571172540',
    name: 'Miranda',
    birthday: '12/12/1983',
    bio: 'Doctor',
  },
  {
    id: '1476279359358140',
    name: 'Alissa',
    birthday: '2/11/1990',
    bio: 'Comedian',
  },
  {
    id: '1140849052644433',
    name: 'Behati',
    birthday: '3/23/1991',
    bio: 'Developer',
  },
  {
    id: '912478262117011',
    name: 'Rosie',
    birthday: '9/4/1989',
    bio: 'Artist',
  },
  {
    id: '173567062703796',
    name: 'Kendall',
    birthday: '8/17/1992',
    bio: 'Truck Driver',
  },
]
```

error is

```
TypeError: _app2.default.database is not a function. (In '_app2.default.database()', '_app2.default.database' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

how can solve this error
I try to connect with realtime database

[image]

can someone help me this issue
what wrong in codes
I wonder why it difficult to connect with firebase.What are gross mistake in this code
database connection is not simple in firebase .Really suprise .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're importing Firebase v9 (as far as I can tell) with:

```
import database from 'firebase/database'
```

This import means you're using the new modular syntax of the v9 SDK.

But then in your code you try to access the database with:

```
firebase.database()...
```

And this is the v8 style syntax, which you didn't import.

If you want to continue to use the v8 syntax, you should import the `compat` library as you did for `import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'`. So:

```
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'
```

Also see the Firebase [v9 upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: you are awesome bro .Now can solve this problem .imported as you say .But console warning get that is setting a timer for long period of time.How can fix this too and possivle unhandle promise rejection